# Match one or more keywords defined in array

Tags: php

I want php function to check if a given string contains a word defined in array of keywords

for example :

```
$string = "Unmade in the USA"

 function check($string){
 $keyword = array( 'France',
         'USA',
         'China',
         'Germany');
}
```

the required function should return true if the given string contains one or more word/words defined in $keyword array. false otherwise.

Thanks for help

Comment: why can't you just use [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)? And note that this site is for programming questions. "I want" is not a question. It's a to-do list, and we are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: @Marc B, sorry for bothering you

Comment: @NDM, thank you very much for the given link, that helped me